# What does $\equiv$ mean when referring to a function in analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

In terms of analysis, what is meant by $f(x) \equiv 0$? Just that $f$ is the constant function equal to zero?

Comment: It means f(x) is divisible by some number since the remainder is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, usually read as "$f(x)$ is identically $0$" (or any other constant) to distinguish from the times we might be solving $f(x) = 0$.

More generally, it's sometimes used a symbol for "is defined to be equal to...", much like "$:=$" or "$\overset{\text{def}}{=}$".